# How to store filters data in the local storage in MUI DataGrid component?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I am using React JS with DataGrid component from MUI
I need that when the user filters the table and then reloads the page the filters should be apply again from the local storage, How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This article might help : https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/state/#save-and-restore-the-state-from-external-storage

You can get the state and save it in the local storage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).